# Objective-C - Hex to unsigned char array algorithm

Tags: objective-c, arrays, hex

Suppose that we have hex 0x83 which has binary representation:

```
  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  <- binary
-------------------------
  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  <- position
-------------------------
 13 12 11 10 03 02 01 00  <- mapping value
```

If there is a "1" on specified position the value show be placed in output array. In above example output array should be:

```
unsigned char output[] = { 0x13, 0x01, 0x00 }
```

On the other hand, if the input is 0xFF the output should be:

```
unsigned char output[] = { 0x13, 0x12, 0x11, 0x10, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 }
```

I know that I can loop through input but, if it possible, I would like to do it in "smarter way" (maybe shifting or some kind of dictionary).

Comment: No looping with byte shifting is the only way, other than lots of `if` statements...

Comment: what is the mapping values? looks like they are some kind of 4-based system? like for 9th position it would be '20'?

Comment: There are only 8 eight positions and no more.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it to a mask, smth like this:

```
//    1111 1110 FE
//    1111 1101 FD
//    1111 1011 FB
//    1111 0111 F7
//    1110 1111 EF
//    1101 1111 DF
//    1011 1111 BF
//    0111 1111 7F

int i = 0x83;

NSMutableArray *ar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if ((i&0x7F) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x13]];
}
if ((i&0xBF) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x12]];
}
if ((i&0xDF) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x11]];
}
if ((i&0xEF) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x10]];
}
if ((i&0xF7) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x03]];
}
if ((i&0xFB) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x02]];
}
if ((i&0xFD) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x01]];
}
if ((i&0xFE) != i) {
    [ar addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0x00]];
}
```

Comment: I think that's what loops are `for` (get it)?

Comment: And all of the `if` statements can be simplified: `if (i & 0x80)`, `if (i & 0x40)`, etc. down to `if (i & 0x01)`. In other words, just check if the specific bit is set or not.